# WiX Toolset Insignia error INSG0001 Access to the path is denied

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, installation, wix, digital-signature

Hi I use the WiX Toolset v3.11 to deploy several projects. This has worked without issue for some time. I use the Post-build Event Command Line in Visual Studio 2017 to digitally sign my installation package. Unfortunately something went haywire with the USB on my computer so I had to re-Install Windows 10. Since the re-install the Post-build commands no longer run. I'm hoping the solution is something simple I've overlooked.

Post build commands

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\insignia.exe" -ib Installer.exe -o engine.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f "c:\users\username\documents\Cert.pfx" /p "password" /d "My Software" /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 /td sha256 "engine.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\insignia.exe" -ab engine.exe Installer.exe -o Installer.exe 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f "c:\users\username\documents\Cert.pfx" /p "password" /d "My Software" /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 /td sha256 "$(TargetPath)"
del engine.exe
```

The output from the build

```
Windows Installer XML Toolset Inscriber version 3.11.1.2318
2>  Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved.
2>Insignia.exe(0,0): error INSG0001: Access to the path is denied.
2>  Exception Type: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
2>  Stack Trace:
2>     at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
2>     at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
2>     at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)
2>     at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Inscriber.InscribeBundleEngine(String bundleFile, String outputFile)
2>     at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Tools.Insignia.Run(String[] args)
2>  Done Adding Additional Store
2>  Number of errors: 1
2>EXEC(0,0): error : File not found: engine.exe
2>  Windows Installer XML Toolset Inscriber version 3.11.1.2318
2>  Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved.
2>Insignia.exe(0,0): error INSG0001: Could not find file 'C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\My Sotware\Bootstrapper\bin\Release\engine.exe'.
2>  Exception Type: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
2>  Stack Trace:
2>     at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
2>     at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
2>     at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
2>     at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Inscriber.InscribeBundle(String bundleFile, String signedEngineFile, String outputFile)
2>     at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Tools.Insignia.Run(String[] args)
2>  Done Adding Additional Store
2>  Successfully signed: C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\My Software\Bootstrapper\bin\Release\Installer.exe
2>  Could Not Find C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\My Software\Bootstrapper\bin\Release\engine.exe
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\wix2010.targets(2832,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\insignia.exe" -ib Installer.exe -o engine.exe
2>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f "c:\users\username\documents\Cert.pfx" /p "password" /d "My Software" /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 /td sha256 "engine.exe"
2>"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\insignia.exe" -ab engine.exe Installer.exe -o Installer.exe 
2>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f "c:\users\username\documents\Cert.pfx" /p "password" /d "My Software" /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 /td sha256 "C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\My Software\Bootstrapper\bin\Release\Installer.exe"
2>del engine.exe" exited with code -1.
2>Done building project "Bootstrapper.wixproj" -- FAILED.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, the solution was indeed simple, my security software BitDefender Total Security 2018 was blocking access.

To allow access

- Open Bitdefender
- Click 'View Features' link (Towards the right hand side)
- In the 'Sale Files' tile click on 'Application Access'
- Toggle 'WiX Toolset Inscriber' to Allowed

Comment: so glad to hear that your issue is solve, please mark it as answer and that will help other community members easier search this helpful information, thanks in advance.